# What is the best way to deal with posts that leave code out of code blocks to satisfy the code/text ratio requirement

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

I just came across this post which had some code that was not properly formatted to be within the code block.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43142009/i-have-a-code-a-for-sending-data-to-sql-server-from-android-device-client-but

I went to edit it to clean up the post, but I could not save the changes as after the edit there was not enough text to satisfy the code/text ratio requirement.

What is the best way to deal with posts that circumvent the code/text ratio requirement by leaving code outside the code block?

Comment: I don't know that this particular user was actively trying to circumvent the requirement so much as they pasted code without formatting it correctly to begin with (though I can't explain the missing }s from each class definition) and unintentionally avoided getting hit with the error.

Comment: @BoltClock Sorry, I did not mean to imply that the circumvention was intentional. Still I am wondering what the best way to deal with it is. Even if just accept it and move on is the recommended course of action.

Comment: @BoltClock similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43156589/how-to-switch-class-for-div-using-js).. only here the jsfiddle link is put as text to avoid pasting code..

Comment: @suraj: Now *that* is intentional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the vast majority of cases like this, what little text there is is not enough to describe the problem. This is basically why the requirement is in place.

Only the asker is in a position to describe the problem that *they* are having. So hand the responsibility over to them by flagging the question for closure. I've closed the question; see the close reason I used for a suitable reason to choose when flagging such questions.