# How to review/edit poorly formatted code-only question?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I just came across a first [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208211/adding-the-text-box-control-in-the-access-form-design-using-vbs-but-getting-type) that only contained code, but only about half of the code was also formatted as code. I started editing the post and (correctly) marking everything as code, but I could not submit the edit because there's a check that ensures that the post isn't code-only. The question seems answerable using the code and the information provided in the title of the post, but does not provide enough information to make an edit that passes the "your post mostly contains code" checks.

What would be the right way to review questions like this?

Comment: vote to close as unclear and downvote as not useful. Consider adding a comment to the OP detailing what's wrong i.e. no problem statement, no requirements as to what happens/what's supposed to happen etc.

Comment: Since you don't have enough rep to vote to close, use the flag link and the "should be closed..." options..

Comment: To avoid code-only, copy the title into the post, where it ought to be anyway.

Comment: This is a much more egregious case of what is described here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346324/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-posts-that-leave-code-out-of-code-blocks-to-sa (and is probably a duplicate of that question for that reason)

Comment: @philipxy I tried that, but it's still too much code to pass the test.

Answer (score 4):

That question is unsalvageable by anyone other than the asker. Don't waste your time editing it, because you're not going to be able to fabricate a question out of thin air on their behalf. Just flag it for closure and move on.

Comment: I edited the post. There was some text in Edit Summary.