# Acceptable question with too low text-to-body ratio

Tags: discussion, edits, new-users, code

Not long ago I gained the privilege to review queues and I try to help the community a little by handling issues in the queues.

My issue is with questions with low text-to-body ratio. Often askers who posts such questions doesn't use proper code formatting and ratio isn't met. Other times this question is acceptable but asker adds some not important text (which should be removed) to meet this ratio.

I know that this meta post ([What is the best way to deal with posts that leave code out of code blocks to satisfy the code/text ratio requirement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346324/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-posts-that-leave-code-out-of-code-blocks-to-sa)) suggests we should not edit such questions but simply close them (accepted answer mentions "vast majority of cases like this...")

But:

1. What about new users and "be welcoming" policy? If their question is good (or almost good) and can be salvaged by edit, what should I do? If voting to close - which reason is the most appropriate? Example (before edits): [hadoop mapreduce why mapper map progress decrease? and why reduce percent 100% when mapper not finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51978827/hadoop-mapreduce-why-mapper-map-progress-decrease-and-why-reduce-percent-100-w)
2. When I see question I can improve I try to edit it. It's really irritating when I spend few minutes to fix formatting, typos, rephrase some sentences and when I remove some not essential parts of question then I get message that my edit can't be saved. So my work is in vain and I have to drop the edit. Should I post edits with partial fix and leave the worst parts unedited? (Example: same question linked above)

I'm guessing that there are some users that can edit without text-to-body ratio requirements. Is that correct? What are the privileges needed for that?

EDIT:

I guessed correctly! Today I spotted user that was able to perform edit which clearly must invalid text-to-body ratio. What are the rules here?

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52114957/2

Is this edit considered good? According to posted above posts, this question should be closed without editing.

Comment: oops, I closed the question before I saw your post on meta https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAiDt.png

Comment: No problem @SamuelLiew. I know that this question had severe issues, but I'm more asking in general. It definitely isn't the only question with same problem.

Comment: 'What about new users and "be welcoming" policy?' well, OK, so the user already broke the CoC by deliberately onfuscating their code to satisfy a rule, but a downvote, close vote and eventual deletion is sufficient censure.  There is no need for any futher action.

Comment: @MartinJames In general I agree - if new user don't care about SO quality, than it's not place for him. But we help new users by editing their question, formatting code and so on. Why that user should be different? If SO would (unlikely) decide to just delete all low-quality, low-effort questions I would be satisfied. But right now guidelines are different and text-to-body ratio makes it harder to treat all users in same manner (some question we can edit and some just vote to close and delete)?

Comment: @franiis 'we help new users by editing their question' well, the meaningful, explanatory text, sure. Fixing punctuation/grammar etc from, ,say, an ESL user is fine, and I'm happy to help with that.  I do not edit OP's code in a question, whether in a code block or no - it's what the user tested, (supposedly:). and I will not modify it.

Comment: @MartinJames Yeah, of course. I meant "code formatting" - sometimes with indentation. I never change posted code, but often add 'code styling` using `style` or mentioned indentation.

Comment: **Downvotes and closevotes have nothing to do with being welcoming**. Closing a question without helping the OP to improve it is always acceptable behavior, although OP is not helped. Remember that they can always read the help center.

Comment: On the other hand leaving a "it's really easy just google the title" is (somewhat) helpful, but not welcoming.

Comment: The policy has always been to delete low-quality or low-definition-effort. There are just too much of them that nobody can handles.

Comment: _"What are the privileges needed for that?"_ I think this comes with [editing privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) at 2k reputation.